# Is there a way to get the java file/line number?

Tags: java

In C/C++ the filename is returned by **FILE** and line number is returned by **LINE**.
Java does have a getFileName(), but does not seem to have a corresponding getLineNumber().
It would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(this.getFileName() + this.getLineNumber() + e.getMessage());
}
```

Is there a way to get the java file/line number?

Comment: It may be too much, but you can do `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Actually, e.printStackTrace() is much more useful than getting filename and line number of where you *report* the error.

Comment: Why does the JavaBeans IDE warn: "e.printStackTrace() should be removed?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StackTraceElement frame = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0];
    System.out.println(frame.getFileName());
    System.out.println(frame.getLineNumber());
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it is better to do Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() rather than constructing an Exception. Both are valid and working solutions though :)

Comment: @Alain O'Dea I agree.  I was not aware of/forgot about Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

Comment: Up to date link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html