# Is there a way to link to console text to source code in Flash Builder?

Tags: flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

Is there a way to link to source code in console text in Flash Builder? It is the same as this question but for Flash Builder.

[How to get Eclipse Console to hyperlink text to source code files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469445/how-link-eclipse-console-text-to-source-code)