# Using __LINE__ and __FILE__ macro in Eclipse CDT and can be linked to the specific line of code

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, macros

In C or C++, you can use the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros to refer to the current line/file of code. 
I wonder if it is possible if to print the line/file in Eclipse console window so that I can click it and be brought to the referenced line in the code. This can be done in compilation for WARNING or ERROR messages, which you can click  to see the code directly. Is there any format/protocol to tell Eclipse to link to a specific piece of code directly from the Eclipse console?

Comment: [This may be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469445/how-link-eclipse-console-text-to-source-code).

Comment: I printout the format (%F:%L). seems it doesn't work for CDT. cannot link to the code