# Eclipse MessageConsole: cannot generate clickable link as (Filename.java:LineNumber)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using a `MessageConsole` in Eclipse to display output information. The output is formatted into `Error 1 - (MyClass.java:10)`, which is expected to generate a clickable link to code (MyClass.java line 10, in this case), since the console should be able to parse the pattern `(FileName.java:LineNumber)` automatically as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469445/how-to-get-eclipse-console-to-hyperlink-text-to-source-code-files).

However, it failed to work this way. But when I use `System.out.println()` to output this pattern directly in the plugin Eclipse, the link can be generated.

I also considered the possibility of multiple consoles in the plugin, but streaming the patterned text to other consoles did not work either. Any insights?

My code is like below:

```
ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole( name, null );
conMan.addConsoles( new IConsole[]{myConsole} );
MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
out.println("Error 1 - (MyClass.java:10)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching for Java code links is only done for consoles which have the `javaStackTraceConsole` console type.

So you can use the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners` extension point to define your own pattern matcher to do the same thing for your console.

Or you can use the:

```
public MessageConsole(String name, String consoleType, ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor, boolean autoLifecycle)
```

constructor to specify the console type for your console to match the existing matchers.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the messageConsole.addPatternMatchListener to do the trick, as suggest by you. I also tried the constructor approach and gave the consoleType argument a value of "javaStackTraceConsole". It won't work because the MessageConsole cannot be cast to JavaStrackTraceConsole.